# Jmeter - jsr223 - Error with external library

Tags: jmeter, jsr223

Jmeter - jsr223 - Error with external library

My java code with import org.web3j, run as expected, no error

```
package test;

import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import org.web3j.crypto.Credentials;
import org.web3j.crypto.Sign;
import org.web3j.utils.Numeric;

public class test2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String privateAccountKey = "privateAccountKey ";
        Credentials credentials = Credentials.create(privateAccountKey);
        String message="messageABC";
        byte[] messageBytes = message.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

        Sign.SignatureData signature = Sign.signPrefixedMessage(messageBytes, credentials.getEcKeyPair());

        byte[] value = new byte[65];
        System.arraycopy(signature.getR(), 0, value, 0, 32);
        System.arraycopy(signature.getS(), 0, value, 32, 32);
        System.arraycopy(signature.getV(), 0, value, 64, 1);
        System.out.println("signature: " + Numeric.toHexString(value));


    }

}
```

In jmeter, I use JSR223 PostProcessor

[image]

I have added core-5.0.0.jar to folder apache-jmeter-5.5\lib\ext (Download from https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.web3j/core/5.0.0) and restart jmeter

After run, error is shown javax.script.ScriptException: Sourced file: inline evaluation of: `import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets; import org.web3j.crypto.Credentials; i . . . '' : Typed variable declaration : Class: Credentials not found in namespace : at Line: 7 : in file: inline evaluation of:` import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets; import org.web3j.crypto.Credentials; i . . . '' : Credentials
in inline evaluation of: ``import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets; import org.web3j.crypto.Credentials; i . . . '' at line number 7

[image]

Please advise
Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

1. You should place any 3rd-party .jar libraries to **lib** folder. **lib/ext** is for JMeter Plugins. See [JMeter Classpath](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath) user manual entry for more details.
2. `org.web3j.core` library doesn't contain `org.web3j.crypto.Credentials` class, you will need to add [this library](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.web3j/crypto/5.0.0) to JMeter's **lib** folder
3. [Since JMeter 3.1 you're supposed to be using Groovy language for scripting](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) especially when it comes to resource intensive cryptographic operations, see [Beanshell vs. JSR223 vs. Java For JMeter: Complete Showdown](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/beanshell-vs-jsr223-vs-jmeter) for more details so consider switching the language to `groovy` because `java` is not real Java, it's [Beanshell](https://beanshell.github.io/) interpreter